# How do I answer questions regarding relocation

Tags: relocation

I'm applying for a remote position and it's out of state. I need advice on how to answer the question "Why not relocate". I want to be honest but just don't know how to phrase it.

1. I work remotely because I am disabled and it is hard for me to get around.
2. I have kids in high school here and they only have a few years until they graduate.
3. The job is in Texas and I live in California.

Comment: Speaking as a hiring manager, no one expects you to explain *why* you do, or do not, want to relocate. People just expect you to have a preference, or not. Employers often ask "would you relocate?" but I would be surprised if a potential employer would actually ask "why not relocate" - and I would certainly not expect anyone to want more than "because I'm happy where I live" as an answer, or something else similarly generic.

Comment: I would **never answer** a question *why* not relocate.  That borders on asking something like "how old are you" or "give us the password to your Facebook account."  It's simply a given that people want to work remote.

Answer (score 13):

Just say "I've established my family in California and don't want to uproot them." Wanting to work remote because of kids is a very common reason.

Comment: The answer "they want to hear" is "Because I get much more work done remotely" and other such corporate BS.

Answer (score 5):

I have the below line on the very top of all of my public profiles in various wording, which I've been told by experienced recruiters will cut down but not completely eliminate people contacting me about jobs elsewhere, as there are a ton of recruiters that are just plain sloppy and will spam people anyways.

Really you shouldn't have to explain why you don't want to relocate.

Good luck.

---

*** Please read before sending me messages and connection requests

Please do not send me messages for contracts or employment outside of the Twin Cities of Minnesota area or that cannot be done at least 95% remotely. Also I do not work with out of state agencies or blind connect to IT recruiters that have not performed basic research regarding my skillsets and employment opportunities. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with second reason being your main one?

IMHO, it should be sufficient for any employer

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to be honest but just don't know how to phrase it.*

Most of the time, being honest comes with the advantage of simply speaking your mind, no need to "think" how to put your words together.

I'd like to say two points here:

- If you're applying for a remote position, there's very less chance they will actually ask you for a reallocation. Unless they were sure of the roles and OK with working remote - they would not have advertised. I don't know why anyone would want the employee to relocate if the position was advertised as remote.
- Even if anyone ask, you can clearly mention:

  > *I have my family settled down in my current location, thanks.*

  or.

  > *I have my personal things to be taken care of, which will be impossible if I move out, thanks.*

  You *don't have to* give them any reason or details.

Comment: *Unless they were sure of the roles and OK with working remote - they would not have advertised* - umm, no, actually they do that a lot nowadays.